# Check the needed view controller in delegate method tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have 3 `TabBarItems` in `UITabBarController`:

```
<UINavigationController: 0xc76a680>
<SplitViewController: 0xc76a170>
<UINavigationController: 0xca5e6f0>
```

And I have the method in `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"tab selected index %@",viewController);
    if (viewController == nil ) // I NEED TO IMPLEMENT A CHECk HERE
    {
        //show popup

        return NO; //does not change the tab
    }

    return YES; //does change the tab
}
```

So how to check that view controller which should be selected is the second Navigation Controller? Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code

```
 - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {        
     BOOL result;

     if (viewController == [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]) //assuming the index of uinavigationcontroller is 2
     {
         NSLog(@"Write your code based on condition");
         result = NO;
     } 
     else {
         result = YES;
     }

     return result;
  }
```

Comment: add alert in result = NO part and then return the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for viewcontroller.title property and then make the decision. Assuming that title for both viewcontrollers are different.

Comment: I tried this - but the title is (NULL) for both controllers. Anyway thank you!

Comment: I made a wrong assumption! Generally I assign a title to every viewcontroller that gets loaded. title is user readable and visible and may ensure more accuracy sometimes.